# Check if a string is folder path?

Tags: vbscript

The following VBScript code checks if a string is folder path,

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fso.FolderExists(folderpath) then
   'Do code
end if
```

But this works only if the actual folder exists. What is the VBScript code to check if a string is folder path when there is no actual folder found. Because, the folder will be created from the string after confirmation that the string structure is folder path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.GetParentFolderName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22dyy47c(v=vs.84).aspx) and .FolderExists to check if a full path has a valid head/prefix:

```
>> p = "c:\users\eh\pipapo"
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetParentFolderName(p)
>> WScript.Echo goFS.FolderExists(goFS.GetParentFolderName(p))
>>
c:\users\eh
-1
>>
```